# Google people.searchDirectoryPeople doesn't return peoples photos

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to use `people.searchDirectoryPeople` API to get photos from people in my organization. According to the documentation, I should have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly` access token, which I have provided. But results are missing the `photos` array ( according to the documentation there should be a photos array for each one of the results). I've set the mask to `photos`. If I set it to `emailAddresses,photos` It will return the `emailAddresses` array but not the photos. I can't find what I'm missing here, is there any specific scope that I should add or some other parameter.
[image]

P.S: I've added the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope too, but no luck. Any idea where I should continue looking/investigating?

Thanks!

Comment: I am testing and I am also not getting the photos. Have you tested the [`people.listDirectoryPeople`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople)? From my point of view, this seems like a bug. You can use this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1041029) to reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the root of the problem.
When I added a new user to my account, I added their images from the Google Amin page, but that seems to be the issue. Those photos are not shown when using the People API. When I logged in to the newly created account and changed the profile photo from there, it started showing in the results from API. Maybe it's but if you go back to Google Admin and change it again, it will stop showing again.

Looks like it's a bug in the Google Admin page or it is intended behavior but not mentioned in the documentation.
I've reported an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228791251